# balanced tree-like data structure that resizes to prime sizes

Tags: .net, algorithm, dictionary, hash, tree

Relating to this: [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638520/why-net-dictionaries-resize-to-prime-numbers),

where I found out that .Net dictionaries resize to the next prime size that is at least twice the current size, I was wondering if there is any balanced tree-like data structure that can resize to prime sizes (similar to B-Trees or Binomial trees maybe).

What is the tree-like data structure behind .Net's dictionaries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dictionary uses a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) algorithm, which stores the data in an array, it is this array that is sized/re-sized based on Prime numbers.

.NET [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28VS.80%29.aspx) uses a [Red-Black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) structure to maintain the Key/Value pairs. Since the red-black tree is not stored in a fixed array, but rather as a series on nodes with left/right child nodes, there is not really a concept of sizing anything, as nodes are added to the tree the tree is rotated to maintain the balance.

Comment: `Dictionary` != `SortedDictionary`. And I doubt `SortedDictionary` resizes to primes.

Comment: @marcog, I do not believe I said either of those things? I say Dictionary uses Hashtable, Sorted dictionary uses Red-Black tree and that the tree is **not** stored in an array and there is **not** a concept of sizing anything.

Comment: well it is wise to not allocate memory for nodes that you do not use ... that's true

Comment: Not now that you edited your answer. Please don't hide behind edits.

Comment: @marcog, I assure you that I am not that childish, I only editied the answer to add info on the hash table and the links. I believe you miss-read the initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

.Net's dictionaries are implemented as hastables, which is not a tree-like data structure at all. The question [you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638520/why-net-dictionaries-resize-to-prime-numbers) explains why hashtables are better resized to a prime number.

As for tree-like structures, I can't imagine a purpose for resizing to a prime. It doesn't make much sense. What does make sense though, is resizing a balanced tree structure to a complete tree, which for a binary tree would be 2<sup>n</sup>-1.

Comment: because you can eventually have to resize to huge numbers and keeping extra nodes is memory unefficent while keeping a tree unballanced can give non-linear search times, or even worse

Comment: and so is C++'s std::map implemented as a hastabled, but kept in a red-black tree for fast searching, adding and removall purposes

Comment: @costy It might make sense to resize, but there's no advantage of picking a prime size. `std::map` is implemented as a red-black tree, not a hashtable.

Comment: @marcog, std::map is most typically implemented as a red-black tree and not an AVL tree.

Comment: there was this L9 lecture I saw online where a guy that worked for maintaining the STL for VS2010 said the std::map is implemented with a red-black tree, he also said about another compiler that used red-black trees for std::map but I forgot which one

Comment: @Chris @costy Okay, small mistake. Point was there's no hashtable.

Comment: anyway the bottom line is that there is no need to allocate memory for nodes that you do not use, for for indexing a hashtable any balanced data structure (AVL, red-black, B-trees) will do fine