# C++: find first prime number larger than a given integer

Tags: c++

**Question:** How to find, for a given integer `n`, the first prime number that is larger than `n`?

---

**My own work so far**

I've managed to write a program that checks whether or not a given integer is a prime or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool is_prime (int n)
{
    int i;
    double square_root_n = sqrt(n) ;
    for (i = 2; i <= square_root_n ; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0){
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Input the number and press ENTER: \n";
        cout << "To exit input 0 and press ENTER: \n";
        cin >> i;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (is_prime(i))
        cout << i << " is prime" << endl;
        else
        cout << i << " isn't prime'" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm struggling, however, on how to proceed on from this point.

Comment: What is your problem? What happens when you compile and run your code? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what is the output you get when you run your program? How does this differ from what you want?

Comment: You should add 0.5 to you double value and truncate to int to avoid problems. Otherwise you code looks fine.  Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: seriously, I just went ahead and removed all the non-info and redundancy from your question. Keep things short and precise.

Comment: You can find online tools that will help you format the code. Look for "online C formatter" or similar terms.

Comment: if you see this, why don't you just translate the strings to English? It makes it easier for others to help you. Also, I formatted your code – every code editor should have functionality to do this for you. Use that!

Comment: Variable names that are non-English are a bad idea, because they make it harder for us to help you. Your code is part of your question. Translate it as good as you can; your English is excellent, so this shouldn't be a problem for you!

Comment: "give me tips what I should add / change" is far too broad. Ask a clear question, so that we can answer. @Code-Apprentice explained all the things we need to know from you.

Comment: This code is correct,I am just asking for what i should add so it can cout next prime number

Comment: @MarcusMüller The OP registered for SO today, and describes himself as a high school student, so imho, possibly a more friendly, welcoming and official-SO-guidelines-links explanation of the way of SO questioning could be more appropriate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Personally, I'm okay with non-English variable names. For simple, homework-assignment-type programs, it is usually not difficult to figure out what is going on. The bigger problem with this question is the lack of error messages and other example output.

Comment: Note that `return false`  returns immediately, so the `break` will never execute.

Comment: @Uros.M What do you mean by "next prime number"? Can you explain, in English, the steps needed to do this?

Comment: If your code can check if a given number is prime, you can check the numbers one by one until the code returns true; that's the next prime.

Comment: Is it clear enoguh now?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694432/576911 for a very thorough treatment of this question.

Comment: @Elazar It would be nice if you could give me that in code,please? :)

Comment: @Uros.M first of all, welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! Before you proceed with your coding and the solution of this question of yours, have a look at the SO pages [How do I write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). By reading these guidelines, you will learn to how to ask questions that are more likely to yield good answers for you. Also, asking for code written for you will most likely not yield good feedback, it's better to ask for hints! (Also for your own learning).

Comment: @Uros.M Also note that I took the freedom to attempt to clean up your questions such that it tries to, somewhat, to follow these guidelines (possibly still a bit too broad). Along the sense of posting a _minimal_ example, I remove the declaration of the `is_prime(...)` function and simply move the function definition to proceed `main(...)`. The more minimal example (without loosing clarity), the better. Finally, have a look at [the thread linked to by Howard Hinnant above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475996), which treats this very subject. Good luck with your StackOverflowing!

Answer (score 2):

You have a function `is_prime(n)`, and a number `n`, and you want to return the smallest number `q` such that `is_prime(q)==true` and `n <= q`:

```
int q = n;
while (!is_prime(q)) {
    q++;
}
// here you can be sure that
// 1. q is prime
// 2. q >= n       -- unless there was an overflow
```

If you want to be a bit more efficient, you can check explicitly for the even case, and the increment by 2 each time.

It's a concrete example of a general theme: if you have a test function and a method for generating elements, you can generate the elements that pass the test:

```
x = initial_value
while (something) {
    if (test(x)) {
        // found!
        // If you only want the first such x, you can break
        break;
    }
    x = generate(x)
}
```

(note that this is not a valid C++ code, it's pseudocode)

Comment: perhaps you can generalise your suggestion to avoid multiples of 2, and also of 3,5,7, etc, using a variant of a Sieve of Eratosthenes... just a thought, but undeveloped.

Comment: @Alejandro:  Like is done in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694432/576911 ?

Comment: guess so, nice find

Comment: Admittedly, doesn't use Sieve of Eratosthenes.  But it demonstrates performance that can be gained by factoring out small primes.

Comment: I intensionally avoided the issue of performance / complexity. I thought that this question is more about very simple programming techniques.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
**int k_koren_od_n = (int)(sqrt(n) + 0.5)**
for (i = 2; i <= k_koren_od_n ; i++){
```

To get around casting issues, you might want to add this fix.