# Faster way to find the biggest prime number less than or equal to the given input

Tags: python, algorithm, primes

Given an integer number, I want to find the biggest prime number under it. For example:

```text
input 20 -> output 19
input 100 -> output 97.
```

I already have the simple program given below, but I'm curious about how to make it faster.

```python
def isPrime(x):
  for j in range(2,int(x**0.5)+1):
    if x%j==0:
      return False
  return True

def findPrimeNum(num):
  for i in range(num-1,1,-1):
    if isPrime(i):
      return i

findPrimeNum(600851475143)  # -> 600851475067
```

Comment: Other than 2, prime numbers are odd. Your code doesn't exploit that fact. Thus, there is an easy way to make it at least 50% faster. Since your code is working, consider posting this question on [codereview.se] rather than here -- but first read their posting guidelines if you do.

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://miraclelearningcentre.com/the-pattern-in-prime-numbers/

Comment: You could try Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: I am puzzled that this was marked a duplicate of a question about `isPrime`, when this question is about *finding the next prime number*, not *testing if a given number is prime*.

Comment: @Stef: agreed, so why not vote to reopen? Algorithms for finding the next, or previous prime, may different than testing if a given number is prime.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Done.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question you have, thanks!

I implemented from scratch fully working Python solution based on following algorithms: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (fast generation of primes), [Miller-Rabin Probablity Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), Previous Prime through Sieving.

Full algorithm is as following:

1. We're given number N. And need to find first prime not bigger than N.
2. Through [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) first I generate around 10 000 smallest prime numbers.
3. Sieve of boolean values is created that would be used to sieve the range [N - offset, N]. By sieving I mean marking which numbers are Definitely composite, and which are probably prime.
4. Sieve of boolean value is marked with True at places where we have composite values. This is done by taking every prime P (out of generated) and marking positions in sieve `N - N % P` and `N - N % P - P` and `N - N % P - 2 * P` ..., i.e. starting from `N - N % P` with step P backwards we mark sieve entries with True.
5. Those values that were marked with False in sieve are probably prime values, while True marks are certainly composite. Hence now we check only False entries if they are prime, by using [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Before running a script install just single time PIP packages `python -m pip install numpy gmpy2 sympy`.

For 2048-bit input random integer it takes only several seconds to compute previous prime:

```
SieveTime 0.847 sec, MillerTime 2.810 sec, MillerCnt 188
ReferenceTime 7.736 sec
N 2^2046.803, PrevPrime offset 4254, PrevPrime Reference offset 4254
```

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow68907414#main.py)

```py
import numpy as np, gmpy2, math, random, time, sympy

def GenPrimes_SieveOfEratosthenes(end):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
    composites = np.zeros((end,), dtype = np.uint8)
    composites[:2] = 1
    for p, comp in enumerate(composites):
        if comp:
            continue
        if p * p >= len(composites):
            break
        composites[p * p :: p] = 1
    return np.array([i for i in range(len(composites)) if not composites[i]], dtype = np.uint32)
    
def IsProbablyPrime_MillerRabin(n, *, cnt = 32):
    # According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test
    
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n < 2 or n & 1 == 0:
        return False
    
    def Num(n):
        return gmpy2.mpz(n)
    
    n = Num(n)
    
    d, r = Num(n - 1), 0
    while d & 1 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        r += 1
    
    nm1 = Num(n - 1)
    
    for i in range(cnt):
        a = Num(random.randint(2, n - 2))
        
        x = pow(a, d, n)
        
        if x == 1 or x == nm1:
            continue
        
        prp = False
        for j in range(r - 1):
            x *= x
            x %= n
            if x == nm1:
                prp = True
                break
        if prp:
            continue
            
        return False
            
    return True

def PrevPrime(N):
    primes = GenPrimes_SieveOfEratosthenes(1 << 17)
    approx_dist = math.log(N)
    sieve_time, miller_time, miller_cnt = 0, 0, 0
    for icycle in range(100):
        sieve_size = round(approx_dist * 1.5)
        sieve_begin = N - sieve_size * (icycle + 1)
        sieve_last = N - sieve_size * icycle
        sieve = np.zeros((1 + sieve_last - sieve_begin,), dtype = np.uint8)
        tb = time.time()
        for p in primes:
            sieve[np.arange(sieve_last - sieve_last % p - sieve_begin, -1, -int(p))] = 1
        sieve_time += time.time() - tb
        tb = time.time()
        for i in range(len(sieve) - 1, -1, -1):
            if sieve[i]:
                continue
            x = sieve_begin + i
            miller_cnt += 1
            if IsProbablyPrime_MillerRabin(x):
                miller_time += time.time() - tb
                print(f'SieveTime {sieve_time:.3f} sec, MillerTime {miller_time:.3f} sec, MillerCnt {miller_cnt}', flush = True)
                return x
        miller_time += time.time() - tb

def PrevPrime_Reference(N):
    tim = time.time()
    for i in range(1 << 14):
        p = N - i
        if (p & 1) == 0:
            continue
        if sympy.isprime(p):
            tim = time.time() - tim
            print(f'ReferenceTime {tim:.3f} sec', flush = True)
            return p

def Main():
    N = random.randrange(1 << 2048)
    p = PrevPrime(N)
    p0 = PrevPrime_Reference(N)
    print(f'N 2^{math.log2(N):.3f}, PrevPrime offset {N - p}, PrevPrime Reference offset {N - p0}', flush = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to mirror what several number theory libraries use to implement an efficient next_prime function. The basic layout is identical to yours: an isPrime(x) function, and a loop counting down. Those provide two areas for optimization.

**Optimizing isPrime**
The recommended approach is to use a number theory library for Python like [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html), and a probabilistic primality test like Miller-Rabin repeated an appropriate number of times. This scales fairly well with larger numbers, and you can even get a deterministic primality test by using Miller-Rabin with [enough small bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Testing_against_small_sets_of_bases).

**Optimizing iteration over possible primes**
There is already a [comprehensive guide for optimizing next_prime in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694432/16757174), which basically involves choosing the first k primes (e.g. 2, 3 and 5) and computing all residues modulo their product that could potentially be a prime. Then, rather than iterating over all smaller numbers, you jump between those residues only. To adapt this to previousPrime, we just jump between residues in the opposite direction.

For 2, 3, and 5, those residues mod 30 are L = [1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]. For an integer x > 30, say x = 30*q + r, you would do a binary search over L for the largest element less than r, and iterate backwards in this list:

```py
residues = [1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
small_primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]


def prevPrime(num):
    if num <= 2:
        return 0
    q, r = divmod(num, 30)
    if q == 0:
        return small_primes[bisect_left(small_primes, num) - 1]
    num = 30 * q
    if r <= 2:
        num -= 30
        q -= 1
        idx = len(residues) - 1
    else:
        idx = bisect_left(residues, r) - 1
    num += residues[idx]
    while not (isPrime(num)):
        idx -= 1
        if idx < 0:
            q -= 1
            idx = len(residues) - 1
        num = 30 * q + residues[idx]
    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

## Effecient algorithm to find N prime number:

following are steps to be taken to improve algorithm
**1)**As prime numbers are all odd numbers except 2 as [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,19,23...], so we will iterate loop on odd number list only to check if they are prime numbers.
**2)**remove all those numbers from odd number list that is divisible by a number that is already checked a prime number. 
as **3** is **prime** we will remove all 3*3=9,12,15,...nth_odd number.

### algorithm

`def primeNumbers(nth_number:int):
    prime_number=[True]*(nth_number+1)
    prime_number[0],prime_number[1]=False,False
    #1)check for odd ith iteration only
    for i in range(3,int(nth_number**0.5)+1,2):
        if prime_number[i]:
            #2) remove all odd number from prime number list that is 
            for j in range(i*i,nth_number+1,i):
                prime_number[j]=False
    #include 2 also as we iterated only on odd prime finding
    prime_result=[2]
    prime_result.extend([i for i in range(3,nth_number,2) if prime_number[i]])
    return  prime_result
print(primeNumbers(100))`

**output:**
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]